# AttributeError: 'CogLoader' object has no attribute '_BotBase__extensions'

Tags: discord.py, attributeerror

As a part of learning OOP, I'm trying to create a class that will handle the loading and unloading cogs. However I'm getting the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mirza\Desktop\Work\Working Directory\Project\Bots\2B\bot.py", line 50, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\mirza\Desktop\Work\Working Directory\Project\Bots\2B\bot.py", line 43, in main
    bot = CustomBotClient()
  File "c:\Users\mirza\Desktop\Work\Working Directory\Project\Bots\2B\bot.py", line 21, in __init__
    raise e
  File "c:\Users\mirza\Desktop\Work\Working Directory\Project\Bots\2B\bot.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
  File "C:\Users\mirza\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 671, in load_extension
    if name in self.__extensions:
AttributeError: 'CustomBotClient' object has no attribute '_BotBase__extensions'
```

This the code from `bot.py` that is giving me the error

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv


class CogLoader(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self):
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                try:
                    self.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]} cannot be loaded")
                    raise e

    @commands.command()
    async def load(self, ctx, extension):
        self.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

    @commands.command()
    async def unload(self, ctx, extension):
        self.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")

    @commands.command()
    async def reload(self, ctx, extension):
        self.unload_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")
        self.load_extension(f"cogs.{extension}")


class CustomBotClient(CogLoader):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Bot {self.user} is connected to Discord and ready to roll!")


def main():
    bot = CustomBotClient()

    load_dotenv()
    bot.run(os.getenv("TOKEN"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This is the cog that I'm trying to load

```py
from discord.ext import commands


class Greetings(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(name="GreetME")
    async def greet_me(self, ctx):
        await ctx.send("Hello! {author.user}")


def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Greetings(bot))
```

I'm following a [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQw8cFfZPx0&list=PLW3GfRiBCHOhfVoiDZpSz8SM_HybXRPzZ&index=7&ab_channel=Lucas) tutorial but he didnot used a class for this. So, I'm a loss here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to initialize the `commands.Bot` in your `CogLoader.__init__`

This can be accomplished through the following code:

```py
class CogLoader(commands.Bot):

    def __init__(self, command_prefix, **options):
        super().__init__(command_prefix, **options)
        for filename in os.listdir('./cogs'):
            if filename.endswith(".py"):
                try:
                    self.load_extension(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]}")
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"cogs.{filename[:-3]} cannot be loaded")
                    raise e
```

and

```py
def main():
    bot = CustomBotClient(command_prefix="!")
```

This way, commands.Bot and BotBase, their attributes and their methods are loaded.

Comment: It worked. But I have a question. Even if I don't use `**options` here the code works fine. So, is there a reason I have to take `**options` as parameter ?

Comment: You certainly don't need to, I just added it to show that there are optional arguments you can add to the `commands.Bot.__init__` call, such as `intents` or `owner_id`, whereas the `command_prefix` is required. [Here's](https://nextcord.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#bot) some more info